# Turning graph data with multiple parents into data for jstree Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, jstree

I have this following requirements:

1. Query Wikipedia using SPARQL
2. Use that data to build a tree using jstree.

The data I get from the query could be piece together to show a path from 1 node to another. Basically a graph. Then at the second step, I have to convert it to a tree (with some nuances ommited)

After some processing, I reach the stage with the following data

```
//Object contain all nodes
{Id:[Array of parents]}
```

For example, if I have

```
{A:[B,C],
B:[],
C:[]}
```

means that there are 4 nodes in my tree. `A` has 2 parents `B` and `C` while `B` and `C` belong to root. (Fact is,this data is not suited for a tree, but I need to do it anyway)

The problem being that jstree data model does not allow same ID to be presented so I need to create an additional fake A. The above data would turn to same thing like this for consumption by jstree

```
[
{id:0_A,parent:B},
{id:1_A,parent:C},
{id:B,parent:#},
{id:C,parent:#},
]
```

I am stuck at the idea how to do this. I have a faint feeling that I need to recursively go through each element in the parent array till there is only 1 element in their parent array and create additional fake node accordingly. But I cannot make up a comprehensive way to do it.

Example:

```
{A:[B,C,D],
 B:[],
 C:[],
 D:[B,C]
}
//Recursively following B,C,D in A will give us the result that 4 fake A are needed
//The same in D. Following B and C will lead to 2 node that only have 1 or less result in their parent array--> 2 fake D
```

would turn in

```
[
{id:0_A,parent:B},
{id:1_A,parent:C},
{id:2_A,parent:0_D},
{id:3_A,parent:1_D},
{id:B,parent:#},
{id:C,parent:#},
{id:0_D,parent:B},
{id:1_D,parent:C},
]
```

jsfiddle of the tree above http://jsfiddle.net/2wrcdvjq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem being that jstree data model does not allow same ID to be
>   presented

This is not completly true, actually it doesn't care at all. It is more that the HTMLTree has it that way that *each node can have one parent only*.

> [A node A is inserted into a node B when the insertion steps are
>   invoked with A as the argument and A's new parent is B.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-trees)

[JSTree uses appendChild to append the node with id to the parent - thus removing it from other subtrees/leafes.](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/src/jstree.js#L2325)

But if you e.g. use this one

```
[
  {id:'B',text: '#', parent: '#'},
  {id:'A',text: Math.random(), parent: 'B'},
  {id:'A',text: Math.random(), parent: 'B'}, 
  {id:'A',text: Math.random(), parent: 'B'}, 
  {id:'A',text: Math.random(), parent: 'B'}, 
  {id:'A',text: Math.random(), parent: 'B'}
]
```

they will all be shown in B

The best i can think of you can do is pass a callback to `core.data` and populate the children or to assume there will be children and populate on open.

Variation 1 - populate on construct

Variation 2 - lazy daisy - on after_open (i made this one circular to emphasize its advantage)

1. On Construct

```js
$(function () {

  let dat = {
      A:['B','C','D'],
      B:['#'],
      C:['#'],
      D:['B','C']
  }
    function populate(objId){

 
 let rtn = []
 for(let key in dat){
  
   if(dat[key].includes(objId)){
    
    
     rtn.push({
       text:key,
        children: populate(key)
      })
    }
    }
    return rtn
  }
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "core" : {
            "data" : function (obj, cb) {
                        cb.call(this,populate(obj.id))
            }
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

2. Lazy Daisy:

```js
$(function () {

  let dat = {
      A:['B','C','D'],
      B:['#'],
      C:['#'],
      D:['B','C','A']
  }
  function populate(objId){

  
  let rtn = []
  for(let key in dat){
  
      if(dat[key].includes(objId)){


          rtn.push({
            text:key,
            children: ['...']
          })
      }
    }
    return rtn
  }
    $('#jstree2').jstree({
        "core" : {
          check_callback : true,
            "data" : function (obj, cb) {
            
            cb.call(this,populate(obj.id))
            }
        }
    }).on('after_open.jstree', (e, openNode) => {
        
            let children = populate(openNode.node.text)
            
            $(e.currentTarget).jstree("delete_node", openNode.node.children)
            if(children.length)
            for(let newNode of children)
            $(e.currentTarget).jstree("create_node", openNode.node, newNode)
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="jstree">
</div>

<div id="jstree2">
</div>
```

Comment: While it does not directly answer my question, the code above does help me to convert my data to the alternative form that jstree "accepts". I decided to goes for an randomized, unique id approach.